# Como posso pedir uma confirmação ao usuário num arquivo bash?

Tags: shell, bash

Preciso exibir uma mensagem na Console e pedir uma confirmação. Por exemplo, pedir que o usuário digite `SIM` para continuar, e verificar isso.

Comment: Em complemento as respostas abaixo... se for *bash shell*, pode usar a variavel TMOUT para definir um timeout ao usuário e para evitar problema de maiusculas/minusculas : `if echo "$resp" | grep -qi "^sim$" ; then `

Answer (score 10):

Pelo que entendi uma solução possível é esta abaixo :

```
echo "Tem certeza que blá, blá, blá ? Digite SIM para continuar ou qualquer outra coisa para terminar"
read resp
if [ $resp. != 'SIM.' ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

Para pedir uma confirmação você também poderia usar o seguinte:

```
echo "Confirmacão... (sim/não)"
read CONFIRMA

case $CONFIRMA in 
    "sim")
        # ...
        # ...
    ;;

    "não")
        # ...
        # ...           
    ;;

    *)
        echo  "Opção inválida."
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 6):

O parametro `-n 1` faz com que o comando `read` aguarde pela digitação de apenas um caracter, sem a necessidade de pressionar o enter.

O comando `read` possui uma variavél de retorno default chamada `$REPLY`, dipensando a declaração de uma variável.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Continuar (S/N)? " -n 1 -r

echo

case "$REPLY" in 
  s|S ) echo "Sim" ;;
  n|N ) echo "Nao" ;;
    * ) echo "Invalido" ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa interessante para casos assim é usar o comando `select`

Algo assim:

```
select i in SIM NAO
do
    case "$i" in 
        "SIM") 
            echo "continuar"; 
            ;; 
        "NAO")
            echo "parar"
            exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            echo "opção inválida"
            exit 0
            ;;
     esac
done
```

Veja mais aqui: http://rberaldo.com.br/curso-de-shell-script-modulo-1-scripts-shell-estruturas

Answer (score 1):

Usando read, como funcao:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

true=1
false=0

confok(){
    read -p "$1 [S/n]"
    [[ ${REPLY^} == "" ]] && return $true
    [[ ${REPLY^} == N ]] && return $false || return $true
}

confno(){
    read -p "$1 [N/s]"
    [[ ${REPLY^} == "" ]] && return $false
    [[ ${REPLY^} == N  ]] && return $false || return $true
}

confno "Remover?"
LOK=$?

if (( $LOK )); then
    echo "Sim"
else
    echo "Nao"
fi

confok "Continuar?"
LOK=$?

if (( $LOK )); then
    echo "Sim"
else
    echo "Nao"
fi
```

Output:

```
Remover? [N/s] n
Nao
Continuar? [S/n] s
Sim
```